# mysql_connect() using http protocol

Tags: php, mysql, http

I am trying to connect to a MySql server (not localhost) from my computer using the code below. It is giving this error:

**Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] Connection refused (trying to connect via tcp://10.6.3.6:3306) in  on line 7**

I wonder if we can use the http protocol to connect instead of tcp that is being used by default? I searched quite a bit on how to change the protocol, but most of the answers were describing how to connect to localhost, and not much about how to connect to another server. Please help.

PS: I am able to connect to the server by going to http://10.6.3.6/phpmyadmin/...). So I am sure the server is up.

My Code

```
<?php

$db_hostname = '10.6.3.6';
$db_database = 'db_user11';
$db_username = 'db_user11';
$db_password = '########';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: Please add the code inside the question for easy reference now and in the future.

Comment: Sorry. It is my first question; didn't know the convention.
Thank you everyone for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, HTTP is layered on top of TCP/IP.
In order to connect to something via HTTP, it needs to run an HTTP server. MySQL does not run an HTTP server and there's no current/realistic/supported way to tunnel an SQL connection through HTTP. Even if there was, HTTP is not exactly the best protocol for this.

In short: no. You're trying to solve the wrong problem. You need to configure your MySQL server to allow connections from other machines over the network, give the user you're trying to connect with appropriate permissions to connect from other machines and make sure the MySQL server is reachable from other machines.

Comment: Thank you. I think I cannot do much about it then, as I don't have the necessary permissions to MySQL server.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. HTTP is not a protocol suitable for this.

You are talking about 2 processes communicating here (MySQL Server and your app) and they either do it via shared memory, pipes or sockets. Those are the 3 ways that processes communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the `phpmyadmin` is hosted on that server, does not neccesarily mean that the database server is in the same IP address. Please ask the domain administrator to give you the details of database server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just check and  make sure the mysql user account you are connecting with has proper permissions set for remote access.

In other words, this may be obvious but make sure the user has valid remote credentials.

On the command-line ( if you can relate to this ) , one can do this in mysql to add a user allowed to connect from remote connexion:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This would create a user, monty with password some_pass, with FULL privileges on all databases, all tables from *anywhere*. The % is the key here, and is needed for remote access.

MySQL users created through gui tools  often set the host to 'localhost' and this would not allow  a remote connexion.

Hope this helps. Good-luck.